# How to set logging level for an application using a cmd/bash command?

Tags: .net, logging

I have a .NET application configured to use `log4net`. The problem is, there a debug logging lines everywhere in the code and the application keeps logging these to a file even during a normal runtime.

Is there a way I can design a .NET application in such a way logging can be enabled/or logging level set as and when needed?

Also I would like not to have debug logging lines everywhere in the application. I would like it if I can do something like inject debug code on demand. An example of a code snippet from the code base I  I'm working on right now is given below:

```
public void EmailHanderSet(EmailHandler emailHandler)
        {
            try
            {
                _emailHandler = emailHandler;

                AttachIncomingEmailHandlers();

                _userEmailAddress = GetCurrentUserAddress();

                Utils.LogInfo("Username " + _userEmailAddress);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Utils.HandleException("EH Ex ",ex);
            }
        }
```

There are lines line `Utils.LogInfo` all over the code. Thanks.

Comment: Was the below answer helpful? If so, mark it as closed by accepting as answer!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how to do it using cmd/bash command, but by setting the Threshold on the Hierarchy to Level "Off" will disable all logging from that Hierarchy. This can be done in the log4net configuration file by setting the "threshold" attribute on the log4net configuration element to "Off".

For example:

```
<log4net threshold="Off" />
```

Also read [here](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/faq.html#runtime-disable) for more